# How correctly separate a function in a component?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

I need to move the function call from the component to a separate function

```
<MyComponent 
    getLabel={ ({buttonLabel, value }) => {
        console.log('Placeholder');
        console.log(buttonLabel);
        console.log(value ? value.map( c => { return c.label}) : []);
        return 'test;
    }} />
```

I tried to separate it like this:

```
class Results extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }

        this.getLabel = this.getLabel.bind(this);

        getLabel = (buttonLabel, value) => {
            console.log('Placeholder');
            console.log(buttonLabel);
        }
    }

    //this throws a compile error
    /*getLabel = (buttonLabel, value) => {
        console.log('Placeholder');
        console.log(buttonLabel);
    }*/

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
<MyComponent 
    getLabel={this.getLabel} />

        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
}
```

The above example throws error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

on rendering in browser.

If I move the function outside of the constructor, it throws a compile error:

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
>
> Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently
>   enabled

What is wrong there?

This is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
    ]
  }
```

**EDIT**

I don't know why it wasn't working properly before, might be webpack error or so, not sure.

I have provided below the solution that worked for me which is very close to what I intended initially.

Comment: why getLabel in the constructor ?

Comment: Are you running this code with the getLabel in the constructor or outside when you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it in you commented out part. `getLabel(buttonLabel, value) {` would have been the correct start of defining a method.

A syntactically correct way of doing this should be the following:

```
class Results extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};

        this.getLabel = this.getLabel.bind(this);
    }

    getLabel(buttonLabel, value) {
        console.log('Placeholder');
        console.log(buttonLabel);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <MyComponent getLabel={this.getLabel}/>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }]
```

Also what Benjamin mentioned above should be good if your setup is functioning, You can even have the function defined in render it self.

Answer (score 0):

I came back to my original config in webpack's `module.rules`:

```
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
                    plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
                }
            }
        },
```

and removed `.babelrc`.

Then kept only one parameter of the `getLabel` function and it gets all the parameters as an object.

The final code looks like this:

```
class Results extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }

        this.getLabel = this.getLabel.bind(this);
    }

        getLabel = (element) => {
            console.log('Placeholder');
            console.log(element); // element comes as an object with all passed parameters as properties
        }

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
<MyComponent 
    getLabel={this.getLabel} />

        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
}
```